# How to make this layout look the same in both Chrome and IE 11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I made a small page and saw a bug in it. I show you the part of the code where the bug is visible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Flex</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
  .top-menu {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: flex;
  }
  .top-menu__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
  }
  .top-menu__item:nth-last-of-type(n+2) {
    border-right: 1px solid #96be4e;
  }
  .top-menu__link {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
</style>
<ul class="top-menu">
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт-4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт-5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт-6</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 7 с каким-то текстом "какой-то текст"</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 8 тоже с текстом "какой-то текст"</a>
  </li>
  <li class="top-menu__item">
    <a href="#" class="top-menu__link">Пункт 9</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It displays differently in Chrome and in IE 11. I am attaching a screenshot. How to make it display the same in these browsers? What is the problem at all? Why is the display different?

Thanks for your attention.

[image]

Comment: I also test your code in IE and Chrome, the result is the same in both browsers. I think the issue is not related to the above code you provided. You could check if there's other stylesheet applied to the elements and post the code which can reproduce the issue. Besides, you could use F12 dev tools to check the Styles [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbPM7.png) to see if there's any difference in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code from my end on chrome as well as on Internet explorer but the everything looks fine and there is no issue as you can see in the below screen shoot[image: Chrome screenshot]

[image: iexplorer screenshot]